# find-like tool to search (recursively) in MailDir folders by size, sender, recipient, attachment name regex, etc

Tags: shell, email, filter, maildir

I am not looking for a tool like `locate`, that works by creating an index in the MailDir, or generating other runtime files there; I am searching for real-time, direct search on live MailDirs.

The tasks I want to use this tool for:

- Show any combination of filename,, size for mails matching Query
- Remove/Copy/... messages matching Query
- Show/Remove/Extract Attachments from Messages matching Query
- Querying items based on headers, size, attachment data, with operators "greater, smaller, matches [exact], includes and excludes".

Or, also kind-of filling the same need, and helping others:

Is there a mail-client, console-based, slim, available in Debian, that I can run without runtime files and indexes, on arbitrary MailDirs in my file-system, and also capable of generating listings like described above on the command-line?